# Chocolatey: How to install Gnu-Make?

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I have choco installed on powershell. If I run powershell as an admin, and type:

```
choco install gnu-make
```

Choco knows that there *is* a gnu-make package out there, but it can't install it from the repos I have.

How do I connect `choco` to `gnu-make`?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on `chocolatey` around this package is out-dated, and the correct command is:

```
choco install make
```